# Get size of each installed formula in homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I would like to find the size of my installed brew packages so I can see how much space each is taking up. How do I go about doing this from the terminal?

Note:
some of the answers below also include brew cask packages which is also very helpful to this answer.

Answer (score 44):

```
brew list --formula | xargs -n1 -P8 -I {} \
    sh -c "brew info {} | egrep '[0-9]* files, ' | sed 's/^.*[0-9]* files, \(.*\)).*$/{} \1/'" | \
    sort -h -r -k2 - | column -t
```

It display brews like below in sorted form (by size):
[image]

Comment: To me it doesn't work, I get this error:
    `xargs:  : No such file or directory
    Error: No available formula or cask with the name "{}".
    Error: No previously deleted formula found.`

Comment: ^ Same for me on macOS 11.2 Big Sur with Homebrew 2.7.7

Comment: Throws an error `Error: unknown or unsupported macOS version: :mountain_lion` on Homebrew 3.0.4-8-gb024954 on MacOS just updated to Big Sur, but then lists the packages.

Comment: I've added a feature to this program such that you can see the installed leaf packages that depend on these packages: 
`brew list --formula | xargs -n1 -P8 -I {} sh -c "brew info {} | egrep '[0-9]* files, ' | sed 's/^.*[0-9]* files, \(.*\)).*$/{} \1/'" | sort -h -r -k2 - | xargs -L1 bash -c 'echo $0 $1 Leaves: $(brew uses --installed --recursive $0 | grep -E "( |^)$(paste -sd " " <(brew leaves) | sed "s/ /( |$)|( |^)/g")( |$)")'`

Comment: @bvoq Although your comment is not related to the question it is good to know to show package dependencies. However, it takes time and be patient.

Answer (score 35):

riffing off of PTao's solution, here's an ugly improved version which will include a human-readable sum of the combined sized of all package versions

```
for pkg in `brew list --formula -1 | grep -vE '\.|\.\.'`
  do echo $pkg `brew info $pkg | grep -E '[0-9]* files, ' | sed 's/^.*[0-9]* files, \(.*\)).*$/\1/' | awk '{print $1;}/[0-9]$/{s+=$1};/[mM][bB]$/{s+=$1*(1024*1024);next};/[kK][bB]$/{s+=$1*1024;next} END { suffix=" KMGT"; for(i=1; s>1024 && i < length(suffix); i++) s/=1024; printf "\t(all versions: %0.1f%s)",s,substr(suffix, i, 1), $3; }'`
done
```

example output:

```
ack 173.5KB 178.4KB 182.7KB 190.5KB (all versions: 725.1K)
afl-fuzz 556.5KB 561.3KB (all versions: 1.1M)
aircrack-ng 934.2KB 953KB (all versions: 1.8M)
autoconf 1.9MB (all versions: 1.9M)
autojump 325.4KB (all versions: 325.4K)
automake 2.9MB 3.0MB 3MB (all versions: 8.9M)
bash-completion 608.6KB (all versions: 608.6K)
boost 414.6MB 398.7MB (all versions: 813.3M)
cairo 5.9MB 5.9MB (all versions: 11.8M)
cask 166.6KB (all versions: 166.6K)
cmake 31.4MB (all versions: 31.4M)
coreutils 8.5MB 7.9MB 9MB (all versions: 25.4M)
curl 3MB (all versions: 3.0M)
dos2unix 344.4KB 360.5KB (all versions: 704.9K)
ebook-tools 69.6KB 70.5KB (all versions: 140.1K)
eigen 3.5MB 6.5MB (all versions: 10.0M)
```

Comment: turns out this is good enough for most use cases: `du -d 1 -h /usr/local/Cellar | gsort --human-numeric-sort` .  Every call to `brew` is very very slow for some reason... so just checking the size of each folder in the cellar is about 100x faster for me.

Comment: `/[gG][bB]$/{ s+=$1*(1024*1024*1024); next };` needs to be added, since llvm@12 can be 1.5GB

Answer (score 21):

It's not exceedingly pretty, but you can do

```
$ brew list --formula | xargs brew info
```

And it will output something along the lines of

```
...
/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.6 (1,611 files, 34.8M)
  Poured from bottle on 2016-03-31 at 09:35:41
/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7 (1,611 files, 34.9M) *
  Poured from bottle on 2016-12-15 at 09:58:56
..
```

for each package you have installed.  I'm sure some wizard with grep could make this give you a nice table if you have many taps installed.

Comment: I wanted to know the same thing. I have Homebrew 1.3.4. To make the output more readable, use something like `brew list | xargs brew info | egrep --color '\d*\.\d*(KB|MB|GB)'`.

Answer (score 5):

Colored list of all brew packages with size (and overall size of all versions)

```
for pkg in `brew list -f1 | egrep -v '\.|\.\.'`
  do echo $pkg `brew info $pkg | egrep '[0-9]* files, ' | sed 's/^.*[0-9]* files, \(.*\)).*$/\1/' | awk '{print "\033[1;32m"$1;}/[0-9]$/{s+=$1};/[mM][bB]$/{s+=$1*(1024*1024);next};/[kK][bB]$/{s+=$1*1024;next} END { suffix="  KBMBGBTB"; for(i=1; s>1024 && i < length(suffix); i+=2) s/=1024; printf "\033[0m\t(all versions: \033[33m%0.1f %s\033[0m)",s,substr(suffix, i, 2), $3; }'`
done
```

Output looks like this:

[image: brew list with size colored]

Comment: On macOS BigSur 11.1 with Homebrew 2.7.7 
`brew list -f1` leads to `Error: ambiguous option: -f1`.
If you replace this portion with `brew list --formula` you get the output as in the screenshot above. But I don't know if the `-f` (`--force`) argument plays a vital role in the correct calculation of package sizes. Anyhow this argument did not work in any fashion, so omitted it alltogether.

Comment: since macOS BigSur you can go with command:


`for pkg in ``brew list | egrep -v '\.|\.\.'``

  do echo $pkg ``brew info $pkg | egrep '[0-9]* files, ' | sed 's/^.*[0-9]* files, \(.*\)).*$/\1/' | awk '{print "\033[1;32m"$1;}/[0-9]$/{s+=$1};/[mM][bB]$/{s+=$1*(1024*1024);next};/[kK][bB]$/{s+=$1*1024;next} END { suffix="  KBMBGBTB"; for(i=1; s>1024 && i < length(suffix); i+=2) s/=1024; printf "\033[0m\t(all versions: \033[33m%0.1f %s\033[0m)",s,substr(suffix, i, 2), $3; }'``

done`

Answer (score 3):

This shell snippet from https://gist.github.com/eguven/23d8c9fc78856bd20f65f8bcf03e691b will help you

```
for pkg in `brew list -f1 | egrep -v '\.|\.\.'`
  do echo $pkg `brew info $pkg | egrep '[0-9]* files, ' | sed 's/^.*[0-9]* files, \(.*\)).*$/\1/'`
done
```

Answer (score 3):

On version Homebrew 2.7.5
Following command throw an error

```
brew list | xargs brew info | egrep --color '\d*\.\d*(KB|MB|GB)'
```

Error: Calling `brew list` to only list formulae is disabled! Use `brew list --formula` instead.

After adding --formula to brew list command it worked.

```
brew list --formula | xargs brew info | egrep --color '\d*\.\d*(KB|MB|GB)'
```

Comment: Throws an error `Error: unknown or unsupported macOS version: :mountain_lion` on Homebrew 3.0.4-8-gb024954 on MacOS just updated to Big Sur and does not produce any output

Comment: Update: Worked on M1 macOS 11.2.2 (20D80) with Homebrew 2.7.7